# Does Python offer an easy way to calculate lists from a dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to determine the quickest method to read and rank a list.

Three candidates in 3 precincts (will have 230).  Trying to create a Python best way print the highest/lowest candidate in each precincts presented with the precincts containing the largest number of votes.  Should I use Python DB or is there a handy module for this?  I have to *hand* enter the vote numbers, should I use a simple list.  Any ideas appreciated - as you start so shall you end ...

```
precinct 1

Bob 10
Sue 20
Tom 30

precinct 2

Bob 2
Sue 3
Tom 4

precinct 3 

Bob 100
Sue 50
Tom 43
```

Desired Result:

```
precinct 3 Bob 100, Sue 50, Tom 43  (total votes 193)
precinct 1 Tom 30, Sue, 20, Bob 10  (total votes 60)
precinct 2 Tom 4, Sue 3, Bob, 2     (total votes 9)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you running into issues? Please see [ask] and [edit] your question with a [mre] to help us better help you.  As it stands your question is rather open-ended.

Comment: How does the input look like? Anyway, pandas can handle such task: create a dataframe with precincts as rows and candidates as columns, do the row-wise summation, and find argmax of the resulting series